# In video recording audio is not record on here sdk navigation in ios

Tags: ios, here-api

I am try to record video with turn by turn navigation using HERE SDK. Video recording is working perfectly when navigation is not start, but when navigation is going on and try to record video this error comes

```
[avas] AVAudioSession.mm:1074:-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
```

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? We have upgraded our SDK multiple times since this question. Let us know if you required any help still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict between the audio of HERE navigation and that of the video recording app. Our latest SDK allows you to implement volume control and ducking.

> Volume ducking is the practice of manipulating volume based on audio focus. It allows another app such as a phone call to flag its audio as having higher priority and "take over" the current device audio. To grant or request audio focus, call NavigationManager.AudioPlayer.getStreamId() to retrieve the current audio stream and then use it with the Android AudioManager.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/audio-management.html