# Bad map quality since update to sdk 3.2.2

Tags: android, sdk, here-api

Since I updated the android premium sdk to version 3.2.2, the map quality has decreased. We can see some aliasing as in the snapshot below:
[image]

A similar snapshot with the same code before the update:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue in HERE SDK 3.2.2 and it will be fixed with the next version (HERE SDK 3.3) that is released soon.

Comment: please can you answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765776/in-video-recording-audio-is-not-record-on-here-sdk-navigation-in-ios).

Comment: SDK 3.3 is not released at the moment but will come very soon.

Comment: ok thanks. can you answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765776/in-video-recording-audio-is-not-record-on-here-sdk-navigation-in-ios).

Comment: The SDK 3.3 is available now and fix this issue. you can get the new version from developer.here.com